# Ограничить время выполнения qtscript-а

Tags: c++, qt

Как установить максимальное время выполнения скрипта:

```
QScriptEngine myEngine;
QScriptValue three = myEngine.evaluate("1 + 2");
```

Если поставить бесконечный цикл в `evaluate()`, то программа не прекращает работу (вполне ожидаемо). Программы пишут другие пользователи и надо поставить лимиты.

Вопросов два:

1. Как по времени ограничить выполнение скрипта?
2. Если пойти дальше, можно ли установить лимиты на выделяемую память для выполнения скрипта? Скрипты могут дергать нативные С++ функции, а тут контроля уже нет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте вызвать метод `abortEvaluation()` у объекта класса `QScriptEngine`. При этом обратите внимание на то, что потребуется предварительно указать интервал чтения событий, вызвав метод `setProcessEventsInterval()` у объекта того же класса, так как по умолчанию события блокируются.
2. Лимитирования как такового нет. Можно разве что только уведомлять сборщик мусора при достижении определённых затрат посредством вызова метода `reportAdditionalMemoryCost()`.